# Request path contains unescaped characters on axios get request

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, axios

I'm trying to download an image from a link on my website with axios.But it gives me this error

```
TypeError [ERR_UNESCAPED_CHARACTERS]: Request path contains unescaped characters
```

I've searched through a ton of stack answers and questions , but I still haven't found any info on why my link is considered having unescaped characters

```
axios.get(
    "https://somesite.extension/image/cache/catalog/BABYZEN/YOYO2%20PLUS%20KOMPLEKT/3%20YOYO%202%20–%20BASSINET%20-%20WHITE%20FRAME%20-%20GREY%20-%20WEB-1000x1000w.jpg"
  );
```

I tried using encodeURI(url) but then I get a 404 Not Found

I need it to get the image an download it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it

In my case , I have an already encoded URI that should be decoded first then encoded again , everything works like a charm after that

```
url = decodeURI(url);
url = encodeURI(url);
```